# Change the a formula that appears on multiple worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that has about ~100 sheets that all contain the same 'main' button. This button (which is actually a hyperlink) links to the main worksheet of the Excel file. When clicking the button, the main worksheet is opened and cell A1 is selected. The problem is that cell A1 and A2 contain an image, and when A1 is selected, this selection is partially "on top" of the image. Functionality wise this is not a problem but it does not look so nice optically. This leads me to the follow questions:

- Is there a way to make the hyperlink select, for example, A1 to F61?
- If so, is there a way to apply this to the 'main' on every worksheet button automatically?

Comment: By "button", you mean a shape with associated hyperlink?

Comment: Exactly. The way I thought about doing this is like this: find the specific hyperlink on each worksheet -> change the contents on each worksheet tot the new hyperlink.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post?

Answer (score 1):

So, you already know how to change one link. To change all, you may use a macro which:

1. iterates over all worksheets
2. iterates over all shapes in worksheet
3. check if link is the one you want to change and
4. change it

like following:

```
Sub ChangeHyperlinks()
    Dim w As Worksheet, s As Shape, h As Hyperlink
    For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each s In w.Shapes
            Set h = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set h = s.Hyperlink
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not h Is Nothing Then
                If h.Address = "" And h.SubAddress = "Your_Main_Worksheet_Name!A5:B6" Then
                    h.SubAddress = "Your_Main_Worksheet_Name!A1:F61"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Richt click on you shape (button)
- Choose hyperlink
- On the left, choose "place in this document"
- Type the Reference: Main!F61

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do this for that specific hyperlink on each worksheet, without doing this manually?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are trying to achieve is pretty easy. Just follow the below steps

1. Open the worksheet where you want to link to ('The Main Worksheet').
2. Select the range of cells you want to hyperlink to.
3. In the Name Box (Top left where cell address is displayed), try writing a word or any 
   name and then press Enter.
4. Select the button (Design Mode), go to Insert Tab, Click on the hyperlink or link (depends on office version) button.
5. In the dialog box, in the 'Link to' select 'Place in This Document', then in Defined Names group, you will see that word or name you gave to the range.
6. Select that, and click on the OK button.

Done...

Hope this helps !